# hasOwnProperty Always Returning False in For In Loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
    var firstObject = {
        firstName: "James",
        lastName: "Smith",
        nationality: "American",
        age: 12,
        get_age: function(){
            return this.age;
        }
    }
    var secondObject = {
        state: "oregon",
        city: "portland"
    }
    secondObject.__proto__ = firstObject;
    for(var i in secondObject){
        if(secondObject.hasOwnProperty[i]){
            console.log(secondObject[i]);
        }
        else{
            console.log("not my own property: " + secondObject[i]);
        }
    }
```

secondObject extends from firstObject.  In the For In loop, state and city should be classified according to the first if condition while everything else should be classified by the else condition.  When I run the above code, all of my properties / function are classified according to the else condition.  Why is the hasOwnProperty method returning false on all of the properties?

Comment: Don't set the prototype like that - use `Object.create` with the polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.hasOwnProperty[i]    (not a property)
```

supposed to be

```
.hasOwnProperty(i)    (It is a method)
```

You should be using **parentheses** instead of **square braces**.

Comment: They are called "parentheses" or sometimes just "parens", not "regular braces".